# Multiple subscriptions assigned to same Subject

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am using a common pattern of unsubscribing to an observable when a component is destroyed. I want to know if there are any issues with reusing the same Subject across many Subscriptions? Or should I have a new subject for each subscribe call?

```
destroy$: Subject<void> = new Subject();  // can this be reused across many subscriptions?
    
ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.destroy$.next();
  this.destroy$.complete();
}

getData = () => {
  serviceCall().pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))  // same Subject
  .subscribe(res => data = res)
}

getData2 = () => {
  serviceCall2().pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))  // same Subject
  .subscribe(res => data2 = res)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with using the same subject. The only reason you might want to have different subjects associated to each subscription is when you want to be able to stop each of them individually. In your case, if you want to unsubscribe from both at the same time it is perfectly fine.

Here is an example demonstrating your approach: https://playcode.io/1750951

Another common pattern for this case is the usage of `Subscription()`:

```js
private readonly subscriptions = new Subscription();

ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.subscriptions.unsubscribe():
}

getData = () => {
  const getDataSubscription = serviceCall().
  .subscribe(res => data = res)

  subscriptions.add(getDataSubscription)
}

getData2 = () => {
  const getData2Subscription = serviceCall2().
  .subscribe(res => data = res)

  subscriptions.add(getData2Subscription)
}
```

I tend to prefer this second approach as it is less verbose.

Comment: Thank you, I like that approach also. I just couldn't find any documentation if maybe 10 subscriptions assigned to a single subject was too much for it to unsubscribe all of them at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem at all reusing your subject.

In doubt, check the [source code](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/c66657469dc17fbed992e273d7d121e51c00d671/packages/rxjs/src/internal/Subject.ts#L54-L62):

```js
  next(value: T) {
    if (!this._closed) {
      const { observers } = this;
      const len = observers.length;
      for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        observers[i].next(value);
      }
    }
  }
```

You can see that when you call `next`, it'll itself call `next` for all the observers (downstreams).

That said, if you're using a fairly recent version of Angular (I think this came out in v16 or v17) you can do something a lot simpler:

```js
this.someStream$.pipe(
  takeUntilDestroyed(inject(DestroyRef))
).subscribe()
```